# Can't make purchase using SKStoreProductViewController. Apple Store Purchase works

Tags: objective-c, iphone, in-app-purchase, storekit, ios8.3

I am using [DAAppsViewController](https://github.com/danielamitay/DAAppsViewController) in my project and using iPAD Mini device (iOS 8.3) for testing. It is showing all of my apps and launching SKStoreProductViewController. When I try to make a purchase then it asks to sign in with APPLE id. I am using my existing APPLE id with correct password (tried several times) but I am always getting following error

"The Apple ID you entered couldn't be found or your password is incorrect"

But when I click on "Store" at the Top right corner and try to make a purchase directly on APPLE STORE using the SAME Apple id and password then it always works. But in that case, I had to live my app while I need in-app store purchase without leaving my app.

I am just not sure that SKStoreProductViewController is working or not. Can you purchase and download an app using DAAppsViewController's SKStoreProductViewController on a device that has ios 8.3+ version? Can anybody confirm that DAAppsViewController is working on any ios version greater than equal to ios 8.3?

My Apple id belongs to INDIA Store and valid for purchases in INDIA. I have seen in your code that it is not restricted to US Only so it should work in INDIA store if it is working for US Store.

Does it only work for an apple id that is valid for purchases in US APPLE STORE?

I tried changing my iPad setting by setting Country= USA and language = US English but it still doesn't work with my apple id as it is valid for INDIA store. I didn't create a new apple id for US store as I think it is against the iTunes policy to use multiple accounts.

How am i supposed to fix this issue?

Please reply.

Thanks.